# Why is my app not supported by any devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, google-play-console

I tried publishing my first app today and everything seems fine except for these supported devices. No phones are included in this list. The app is mostly just a basic reminder app with an app locking feature. User can select apps to lock for x amount of time, like productivity stuff. I'm not sure what I have to change in my androidmanifest in order to solve this issue.
[image]
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.reminderapp"
    tools:ignore="MissingLeanbackLauncher">

    <permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <categoDry android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Reminder App"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ReminderApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AppsListActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver" />

        <service
            android:name=".LockWindow"
            tools:ignore="Instantiable" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you generating the app for android TV s ? It seems like the list has android tvs only

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured out the issue.

**in the manifest...**

```
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
```

this should be false ->

```
android: required = "false"/>
```

Comment: Remove it completely instead.  Unless you absolutely do not want to run on a device with that feature, you shouldn't specify it.  And I don't see why that would be something you don't want to run on.  You also don't need the touchscreen feature requirement-  name an android device that isn't one.  Even if there is, odds are you'd work just fine with a mouse.  Really almost no apps should have a uses-feature in them.